# How do I access a web service from PowerShell?

Tags: .net, windows, web-services, powershell

I'd like to access a web service with a given (simple) WSDL from within Windows PowerShell.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 20):

```
# Working example of how to use PowerShell (version >= 2) to access a web service.
$svc = New-WebServiceProxy –Uri ‘http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL’

$svc | Get-Member  # Use Get-Member to discover the interface of a web service.
# Get stock quotes. 
$svc.GetQuote(‘BA’)   # Boeing
$svc.GetQuote(‘AMZN’) # Amazon
$svc.GetQuote(‘SBUX’) # Starbucks
```

Answer (score 6):

One way would be to use [WSDL.exe to generate wrapper classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx) - compile the generated source and use the strongly typed classes from PowerShell. The whole generate - compile - instantiate process can be easily done automatically from PowerShell.

If you are using PowerShell 2.0, use [New-WebServiceProxy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315258.aspx) as suggested in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022678/how-to-access-a-web-service-from-powershell/2022762#2022762).