# MOSS 2007 Powershell to run Report Builder Reports RDL

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, reporting-services, report, rdl

MOSS 2007: Client has a library of reports created in Report Builder and SharePoint.  These ".RDL" files are stored in specific folders inside a Report Library.

Are there powershell commands that will allow for this?

1. Given a specific Report Library
2. For each report definitions "RDL" in Library
3. If the report definition last run failed, or it's last successful run is more than X days ago
4. For each subscription inside the RDL
5. Run the subscription Once

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to iterate through what you want, but the actual controlling of the running of subscriptions occurs through the SQL Agent jobs.

So while you can [iterate a SharePoint document library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3371/traverse-through-list-of-documents-using-powershell) easily enough and [List the subscriptions through the Reporting Services web services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.listsubscriptions%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (I would [start here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022678/how-to-access-a-web-service-from-powershell) with trying to call it through powershell), you are not going to be able to manipulate the SQL Agent jobs.

You may get better mileage from creating a stored procedure and [re-running any failed jobs directly from the SQL Server](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/8d548814-88c7-4190-b6ee-0d76f584425c/).